I'm receiving an error when trying to run NEXTJS run dev/ run build locally. Build_ID file is not being created
PS C:\Users\JohnsoD.1254629738.E\01_Development\my-app> npm run dev

my-app@0.1.0 dev
next dev

Error: spawn EPERM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
    at fork (node:child_process:172:10)
    at C:\Users\JohnsoD.1254629738.E\01_Development\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:233:45
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at startServer (C:\Users\JohnsoD.1254629738.E\01_Development\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:219:16)
    at runDevServer (C:\Users\JohnsoD.1254629738.E\01_Development\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:300:23)
    at nextDev (C:\Users\JohnsoD.1254629738.E\01_Development\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:308:11)
    at async main (C:\Users\JohnsoD.1254629738.E\01_Development\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next:155:5) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
PS C:\Users\JohnsoD.1254629738.E\01_Development\my-app> 

Expecting server to start 

